# Split string by last occurence of character within a range

Tags: c#, strings

So I would like to split a string in two by the last space within the first 40 characters, the best solution I could think of:

```
public static void Main(string[] sargs)
{
    var address = "...Are included in two of the " +
                  "substrings. If you want to exclude the " +
                  "period characters, you can add the period...";

    var splitIndex = address.LastIndexOf(' ', 40);

    var address1 = address.Substring(0, splitIndex);
    var address2 = address.Substring(splitIndex + 1, address.Length - splitIndex - 1);
        
    Console.WriteLine(address1);
    Console.WriteLine(address2);

}
```

Is there a better, faster or more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [index](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) and [range](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) operators instead of `SubString` calls

```
var address = "...Are included in two of the " +
      "substrings. If you want to exclude the " +
      "period characters, you can add the period...";

var splitIndex = address.LastIndexOf(' ', 40);

Console.WriteLine(address[..splitIndex]);    
Console.WriteLine(address[(splitIndex+1)..]);
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of this, I think I have to comply with c# 7.0, I'll have to check, but nice nonetheless...

Comment: @anastaciu Well in case of C# 7 you can't really do too much differently. Maybe you can make the `address2` definition a bit more concise: `address.Replace(address1, "")`

Comment: don't forget to cover null and index exceptions. also, maybe using a method (or extension method) that returns a tuple `(string Address1, string Address2)` might give more readability to the context.

Comment: @iSR5 Yepp, that's correct. I've assumed the question is more about the usage of `LastIndexOf` and `Substring`. But yeah splitting computation from presentation is essentail.

Comment: @iSR5 Thanks for the advice. the index exceptions are covered, this is just a test in fact the code is to split large large strings into smaller ones because of a payload list I need to send via post. I added that code for review if you're interested : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276598/217541