# Split large strings into parts by last index of character and by max length

Tags: c#, strings

This is my method to split strings into parts by last index of character and by max length, the rationale for this method is because I have to send, in a payload via `POST`, a list of strings that cannot have more than 40 characters each, suffice to say that I can't cut words in half otherwise it would be much easier.

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitStringByLastIndexOfAndMaxLength(string stringToSplit, int splitMaxLength, char delimiter)
{           
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToSplit))
    {
        if (stringToSplit.Length <= splitMaxLength)
        {
            yield return stringToSplit;
            break;
        }
        var splitIndex = stringToSplit.LastIndexOf(delimiter, splitMaxLength);

        var removeSpace = 1;

        if (splitIndex < 0)
        {
            // if a word is larger than splitMaxLength we still split it
            splitIndex = splitMaxLength;
            // taking care to not remove a non space character
            removeSpace = 0;
        }
        var partialString = stringToSplit[..splitIndex];
        stringToSplit = stringToSplit[(splitIndex + removeSpace)..];

        yield return partialString;
    }
}
```

Usage, example with 40 characters max and split by space:

```
var address = "...Are included in two of the substrings. " +
              "If you want to exclude the characters, you can " +
              "add the periods... ...Are included in of the substrings. " +
              "If you want to exclude the period characters, you can " +
              "add the period... Some more text";

var addresses = SplitStringByLastIndexOfAndMaxLength(address, 40, ' ');

foreach (var address in addresses)
{
    Console.WriteLine(address + " -> " + address.Length);
}
```

Output:

```
...Are included in two of the -> 29
substrings. If you want to exclude the -> 38
characters, you can add the periods... -> 38
...Are included in of the substrings. If -> 40
you want to exclude the period -> 30
characters, you can add the period... -> 37
Some more text -> 14
```

Can you think of improvements to be made?

(This could be made into an extension method but for the time being it's enough.)

Comment: if it's for requests payload, then I would be more worry about memory allocation. use `StringBuilder` or `StringReader` and take advantage of `yield return` this would help decrease memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your method is for requests payloads, you need to use memory-friendly  approaches. I don't know how often the method would be called, and how much requests at average your application would handle in daily bases. In all cases, it would be a good decision to assume the worst case scenarios, so handling them from the start would prevent from future high memory allocations.

Also, I encourage you to use VS profiler or you could use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) in which would help give you a first-glance overview on your code diagnostic measurements. Use test samples to mimic the actual requests payloads, and also try to give at least three real test scenarios,  (one with least , one with average, and one with high API consumptions) just to diagnose and measure the overall performance (with memory allocation) of this addition.

With this, you would know which approach would be better for your case.

This is much better in logic and memory handling. The only missing part is a handling for `splitMaxLength` where it might be `<= 0` or `>= stringToSplit.Length`.

For readability part, `SplitStringByLastIndexOfAndMaxLength` I think if we use `SplitByLastIndexOf` it would be enough, since the method arguments would tell what type of input it's taking, and what it does returns. The only part is hidden, is the use of `LastIndexOf`.

I have modified your version to improve readability and code follow-up. and added some comments to explain the changes that I've made.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLastIndexOf(string source, int blockSize, char delimiter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source)) yield break;

    // in case of invalid block size.
    if (blockSize <= 0 || blockSize >= source.Length)
    {
        blockSize = source.Length;
    }
    
    // reuse it rather than initializing it on each iteration
    var removeSpace = 1;
   
    // reuse it rather than initializing it on each iteration
    var delimiterIndex = -1;
    
    while (source.Length > blockSize)
    {
        delimiterIndex = source.LastIndexOf(delimiter, blockSize);
        
        if(delimiterIndex == -1)
        {
            // if a word is larger than blockSize we still split it
            delimiterIndex = blockSize;
            // taking care to not remove a non space character
            removeSpace = 0;
        }

        yield return source[..delimiterIndex];

        source = source[(delimiterIndex + removeSpace)..];

        // reset
        delimiterIndex = -1;
        removeSpace = 1;
    }

    // return any remaining text. 
    if (source.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: The scenario is for shipments, and it's not called a lot of times for now, but we're counting on a steady increase in requests, the problem is that the remote api can't handle address lines larger than 40 chars, which it's strange but out my scope, they're not extra large, either way the best solution is always better, so thank you for your input. The only problem with your code is that it's keeping leading whitespaces which I don't want to do.

Comment: @anastaciu maybe I'm missing something here, the revised version should output the same results 
 of the original one.. unless if there is something I'm not aware of. would you mind providing me more details?

Comment: As you can see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nb61fc the last 6 lines have a leading whitespace, whereas with my code they don't: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KHg3LW

Comment: It's an easy fix, but still... It would better to add it to the answer. It happens when there is a string larger than 40, the `removeSpace` variable is not reseted to its original value of `1`. An edge case for sure, [not many words are larger than 40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English), but who knows, users are experts in doing unexpected things, as you know.

Comment: @anastaciu I've fixed them. this was due to the how `yield return` works. which I totally missed.  ;)

Comment: Nice, there is still one small problem, there is an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown if the last line is `blockSize` chars long https://dotnetfiddle.net/MgZxBj, my original code had the same problem though, I just fixed it, one of those off-by-one cases. Again, an easy fix `source.Length >= blockSize` should be `>`. I'm accepting anyway, you can fix it later if you want, thanks again.

Comment: @anastaciu I've fixed it in the code. ;) let me know if you need anything.